# What's the algorithm behind ST_LineMerge()?

Tags: postgis

I try to read the PostGIS source code, but the codes are divided in several files which makes it hard to understand. Could somebody tell me the the algorithm behind ST_LineMerge()? A name or a link to the explanation is enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many geometry operations from PostGIS are actually from GEOS (Geometry Engine Open Source) a C++ library, and [geos::operation::linemerge](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/namespacegeos_1_1operation_1_1linemerge.html) is one of those. The [LineMerger Class](http://geos.osgeo.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1operation_1_1linemerge_1_1LineMerger.html) is called from PostGIS through the GEOS C API
 with [GEOSLineMerge_r](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/blob/svn-trunk/capi/geos_c.h.in#L639-L640).

GEOS is a port of the JTS Java Library, where the algorithm was initially implemented and tested with [Class LineMerger](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/linemerge/LineMerger.html). The "linemerge" function is not a simple function, and requires a good understanding of the classes and methods used by the library.

Depending if you want to see the code in C++ or Java, pick one. You can search a mirror of the GEOS source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos), and the JTS source code [here](https://github.com/dr-jts/jts/).

Comment: You are right and I felt a bit lost in these classes. I wonder if you happen to know where I can find an overview of the algorithm implemented in this piece of code.

Comment: The best available overview for the algorithm is from the API documentation already linked in the answer. There are also test cases that use these with C++, C and Java.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.